# C++ Get Another Windows Hwnd In Same Process

Tags: c++, windows

I've made a dll that you can inject into applications. I want that dll to find another window in the same process.
Here you can see a example. The console host (Konsolfönstervärd) is the dll I injected and I want that to find the lockdown-example window hwnd.

[image: Taskmanager Image]

It is very simple to get the handle with the window title. But I don't want to hardcode it for just that application.

```cpp
HWND parentHandle = FindWindowA(NULL, "Lockdown Example");
```

I have also tried some stuff with EnumWindows which basically prints all visible windows and their window title. And in the output of that you can see the "Lockdown Example" window.

```
10828:  TheDll
388:  Lockdown Example
13380:  Microsoft Store
6664:  Program Manager
```

How would I make it only do something when it found the "Lockdown Example" without just giving it a hardcoded title. Instead giving it something like GetCurrentProcessId()

```cpp
static BOOL CALLBACK enumWindowCallback(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lparam) {
    //GetWindowThreadProcessId();

    int length = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
    char* buffer = new char[length + 1];
    GetWindowText(hWnd, buffer, length + 1);
    std::string windowTitle(buffer);

    // List visible windows with a non-empty title
    if (IsWindowVisible(hWnd) && length != 0) {

        cout << GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, NULL) << ":  " << windowTitle << endl;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

EnumWindows(enumWindowCallback, NULL)
```

Comment: _"...But how do I specify that I want that window handle...."_ You don't want to hardcode it but you don't specify what you mean by _"...that..."_ ?

Comment: I edited it now. What I meant was that I didn't want to hardcode the window title for the window to get the hwnd of because its a dll and it can get injected into many different processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came up to a answer with modifying the enumWindowCallback a little bit.

```cpp
BOOL CALLBACK enumWindowCallback(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int length = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd);
    char* buffer = new char[length + 1];
    GetWindowText(hwnd, buffer, length + 1);
    std::string windowTitle(buffer);

    DWORD lpdwProcessId;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &lpdwProcessId);

    // 1. Checks if the current process is not equals to the value given in the lParam
    // 2. Check if the current window is visible
    // 3. Check if its not a empty name
    // 4. Check so it is not the console window
    // All these filters result in to only show all visible windows in the process
    // Which in my case is "17260 | 15800:  Lockdown Example"
    if (lpdwProcessId == lParam && IsWindowVisible(hwnd) && length != 0 
        && GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetConsoleWindow(), NULL) != GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, NULL))
    {
        // Here you can do anything with the window handle (hwnd)
        cout << lpdwProcessId << " | "<< GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, NULL) << ":  " << windowTitle << endl;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Called it with:

```cpp
EnumWindows(enumWindowCallback, GetCurrentProcessId()); // iterate over all windows
```

Comment: @IInspectable .  Lol yeah I meant iterate. My brain is having a tough time with english sometimes xD.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know btw!

Comment: You should call `delete[] buffer;` when `buffer` is no longer needed, to avoid memory leak.